# MySQL - Fetching lowest value

Tags: mysql, group-by

My database structure contains columns: `id, name, value, dealer`. I want to retrieve row with lowest `value` for **each** `dealer`. I've been trying to mess up with `MIN()` and `GROUP BY`, still - no solution.

Comment: What exactly have you tried? By posting your code you could better show that you have put some effort into solving the problem yourself and maybe someone will point the error you may have made. - In the present state of your question you are just asking to do your work for you. - Actually you are just announcing that you could not solve the problem, not even asking for help...

Comment: My approach was simple and wrong: something like `SELECT MIN(value),dealer FROM table_name GROUP BY dealer;` - I knew the solution is somewhere else, so the code would be misleading.

Comment: Why is this code wrong? `SELECT MIN(value),dealer FROM table_name GROUP BY dealer;`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Solution1:

```
SELECT t1.* FROM your_table t1
JOIN (
  SELECT MIN(value) AS min_value, dealer
  FROM your_table 
  GROUP BY dealer
) AS t2 ON t1.dealer = t2.dealer AND t1.value = t2.min_value
```

Solution2 (recommended, much faster than solution1):

```
SELECT t1.* FROM your_table t1
LEFT JOIN your_table t2
ON t1.dealer = t2.dealer AND t1.value > t2.value
WHERE t2.value IS NULL
```

This problem is very famous, so there is a special page for this in Mysql's manual.

Check this: ***[Rows Holding the Group-wise Maximum/Minimum of a Certain Column](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html)***

Comment: What if dealer A have values 1, 2, 3, and dealer B have values 2, 3, 4? Your query will return rows with 1 and 2 for dealer A.

Comment: @WojtusJ No, it won't, check the query once more.

Comment: my comment was to first revision of your answser, without `dealer` condition. :-) Now I can see you edited it, and it is correct - in fact, it is the same as my answer. ;-)

Comment: @WojtusJ Yep, that's a miss. :)

Comment: Both work but here comes another problem - if there are records with the same value, they are both returned. I want to return only one per dealer, so lets assume the should be also grouped by column `time` (lowest is better).

Comment: Wooow !! Thank you

Comment: Mind that there are huge differences in speed. The upper one took 1 to 3 min, while the lower one took 3 s in a bigger query.

Answer (score 3):

```
select id,name,MIN(value) as pkvalue,dealer from TABLENAME 
group by id,name,dealer;
```

here you group all rows by id,name,dealer and then you will get min value as pkvalue.

Comment: The op wants the min value for each dealer.

Comment: That's not what OP really wants, if you have two rows with same dealer but different value, name and id, the OP wants the one with lower value, your query will return both rows.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT MIN(value),dealer FROM table_name GROUP BY dealer;
```

Answer (score 1):

First you need to resolve the lowest value for each dealer, and then retrieve rows having that value for a particular dealer. I would do this that way:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM   your_table AS a
       JOIN (SELECT dealer,
                    Min(value) AS m
             FROM   your_table
             GROUP  BY dealer) AS b
         ON ( a.dealer= b.dealer
              AND a.value = b.m )
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following:

```
SELECT dealer, MIN(value) as "Lowest value"
FROM value
GROUP BY dealer;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name, value, dealer from yourtable where dealer 
in(select min(dealer) from yourtable group by name, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

These answers seem to miss the edge case of having multiple minimum values for a dealer and only wanting to return one row.

If you want to only want one value for each dealer you can use row_number partition - group - the table by dealer then order the data by value and id. we have to make the assumption that you will want the row with the smallest id.

```
SELECT ord_tbl.id, 
       ord_tbl.name, 
       ord_tbl.value, 
       ord_tbl.dealer
FROM (SELECT your_table.*, 
      ROW_NUMBER() over (PARTITION BY dealer ORDER BY value ASC, ID ASC) 
      FROM your_table 
     ) AS ord_tbl
WHERE ord_tbl.ROW_NUMBER = 1;
```

Be careful though that value, id and dealer are indexed. If not this will do a full table scan and can get pretty slow...