# SQL query to select distinct row with minimum value

Tags: sql, database, greatest-n-per-group

I want an SQL statement to get the row with a minimum value.

Consider this table:

```
id  game   point
1    x      5
1    z      4
2    y      6
3    x      2
3    y      5
3    z      8
```

How do I select the ids that have the minimum value in the `point` column, grouped by game?  Like the following:

```
id  game   point    
1    z      4
2    y      5
3    x      2
```

Comment: You need to join the same table in order to get desired result. Check query below in the answer.

Comment: why is game "y" point value 6 instead of 5 in your results?

Comment: Since the OP hasn't responded, I can only assume he meant to ask "grouped by id", and show which game had that lowest score...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Fetching lowest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561774/mysql-fetching-lowest-value)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT tbl.*
FROM TableName tbl
  INNER JOIN
  (
    SELECT Id, MIN(Point) MinPoint
    FROM TableName
    GROUP BY Id
  ) tbl1
  ON tbl1.id = tbl.id
WHERE tbl1.MinPoint = tbl.Point
```

Comment: Can a single inner join be done when writing in an SQL in Microsoft access??

Comment: unneccessary complecation

    SELECT id  , game , MIN(point) FROM tablename GROUP BY id,game

Comment: @SouravSarkar, that will not work That example will return every row from the original query, since it is looking for the lowest point from every id *and* game.  (e.g. the lowest score where id = 1 and game = x is 5; the lowest score where id = 1 and game = z is 4)

Comment: I agree. This is unnecessary. Using Window functions is a much cleaner approach and works irrespective of the schema, also reduces the need for a join.

Comment: As mentioned above, it does not work when there are two rows with same id, and min value like

[id, game, point]   [1, x, 4][1, y, 4]

Comment: wow i love this shorthand way of creating a table of values inplace - can you do this in MySQL? i just tried and got errors....

Answer (score 41):

This is another way of doing the same thing, which would allow you to do interesting things like select the top 5 winning games, etc.

```
 SELECT *
 FROM
 (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Point) as RowNum, *
     FROM Table
 ) X 
 WHERE RowNum = 1
```

You can now correctly get the actual row that was identified as the one with the lowest score and you can modify the ordering function to use multiple criteria, such as "Show me the earliest game which had the smallest score", etc.

Answer (score 23):

This will work

```
select * from table 
where (id,point) IN (select id,min(point) from table group by id);
```

Comment: Which rdbms are you using ?

Comment: Ohh !! i don't know about MySQL ... The query is multi column check in subquery it will work in Oracle .

Answer (score 19):

As this is tagged with `sql` only, the following is using ANSI SQL and a [window function](http://modern-sql.com/slides):

```
select id, game, point
from (
  select id, game, point, 
         row_number() over (partition by game order by point) as rn
  from games
) t
where rn = 1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
FIRST_VALUE(ID) OVER (Partition by Game ORDER BY Point) AS ID,
Game,
FIRST_VALUE(Point) OVER (Partition by Game ORDER BY Point) AS Point
FROM #T
```

Comment: What is `#T`? You haven't defined that so your answer in incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

[Ken Clark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15292049/896802) didn't work in my case. It might not work in yours either. If not, try this:

```
SELECT * 
from table T

INNER JOIN
  (
  select id, MIN(point) MinPoint
  from table T
  group by AccountId
  ) NewT on T.id = NewT.id and T.point = NewT.MinPoint

ORDER BY game desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from room
INNER JOIN
  (
  select DISTINCT hotelNo, MIN(price) MinPrice
  from room
 Group by hotelNo
  ) NewT   
 on room.hotelNo = NewT.hotelNo and room.price = NewT.MinPrice;
```

Comment: A short explanation as to how this code answers the question would greatly improve this answer

Answer (score 0):

This alternative approach uses SQL Server's `OUTER APPLY` clause. This way, it

1. creates the distinct list of games, and
2. fetches and outputs the record with the lowest point number for that game.

The `OUTER APPLY` clause can be imagined as a `LEFT JOIN`, but with the advantage that you can **use values of the main query as parameters in the subquery** (here: game).

```
SELECT colMinPointID
FROM (
  SELECT game
  FROM table
  GROUP BY game
) As rstOuter
OUTER APPLY (
  SELECT TOP 1 id As colMinPointID
  FROM table As rstInner
  WHERE rstInner.game = rstOuter.game
  ORDER BY points
) AS rstMinPoints
```

Answer (score 0):

This is portable - at least between ORACLE and PostgreSQL:

```
select t.* from table t 
where not exists(select 1 from table ti where ti.attr > t.attr);
```

Comment: How is this supposed to answer the question?

Comment: The query selects any record for which there is no other record in the same table with a larger attribute value. If multiple rows have the same minimal attribute value, they are all returned.```
select t.* from table t 
where not exists(select 1 from table ti where ti.attr > t.attr);
```

Comment: Even if your answer is right, by using random table and column names you're making it difficult to see the relation between your answer and the question.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the answers use an inner query.  I am wondering why the following isn't suggested.

```sql
select
   *
from
   table
order by
   point
fetch next 1 row only   // ... or the appropriate syntax for the particular DB
```

This query is very simple to write with `JPAQueryFactory` (a Java Query DSL class).

```java
return new JPAQueryFactory(manager).
   selectFrom(QTable.table).
   setLockMode(LockModeType.OPTIMISTIC).
   orderBy(QTable.table.point.asc()).
   fetchFirst();
```

Answer (score -4):

Try:

```
select id, game, min(point) from t
group by id
```

Comment: i'm getting this error "Column 'student.point' is invalid in the HAVING clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
"

Comment: This will not give desired result. Because you need to group your query with id, game, point to remove error and that will return all records.

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand. What is wrong here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b9c7/8/0

Comment: the code would be :
select id, game, min(point) from tablename
group by id,game

Comment: @Wawrzyniec - the problem is that your result is incorrect.  ID 1, game z, min(point) 4 should be correct.