# sql equivalent to "grep x | head -n1"

Tags: sqlite

I'm beginning to learn sql and have created an sqlite database of what was previously a text file of my daily ip address assignments from Comcast. If I wanted to find the first date that an ip address was assigned with the text file, I could:

```
cat, awk, sort, for/do, grep and head -n1
```

to get a list of the first dates any particular ip address was assigned. How can I do that with sql?

```
select distinct ip from history;
```

does not display the date column, and

```
select distinct ip, date from history;
```

returns all the db entries. What am I not doing? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is exactly a duplicate of this: [SQL query to select distinct row with minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291506/query-to-select-distinct-row-with-minimum-value). You are trying to select the minimum value in the date column (the start date) for every unique IP. You will need to do an inner join and use group by.

Comment: Thank you. Obviously the problem was, in addition to not knowing sql, not knowing the exact verbiage to search. Thanks again!

Comment: Haha. Worked for me on the same site :)