# sql select based on first minimum value from top

Tags: sql-server

I know we already have a few posts on similar topic. But I think this case a bit different and actually I couldn't get the result I wanted by answers given in other posts.

We have a table as below:

```
id   code   amount 
------------------
1     A1      80
2     A1      75
3     A1      70
4     A1      70
5     A1      70
1     A2      92
2     A2      85
3     A2      79
4     A2      50
5     A2      50
```

How can I select the row for "A1" and "A2" based on first lowest value (from top) on "Amount" column? In this case I want the result like below:

```
id   code   amount 
------------------
3     A1      70
4     A2      50
```

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL query to select distinct row with minimum value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291506/sql-query-to-select-distinct-row-with-minimum-value)

Comment: do you need column `id` as well in `select query`? If yes, what is the dataType of that?

Comment: Yes, I need column id - type is "int". And actually there are many more columns to select as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT
    id, code, amount
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY amount, id)
    FROM tbl
) AS t
WHERE Rn = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

you don't need ordering by id. so correct way would be :

```
SELECT
    id, code, amount
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        Rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY code ORDER BY amount)
    FROM tbl
) AS t
WHERE Rn = 1
```