# Laravel Eloquent using "with" with conditions

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I have two tables, say Products and Biddings where one product can be bid by many users. Naturally I have two models:

```
class Product extends Model
{
    public function biddings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Bidding');
    }
}

class Bidding extends Model
{
    public function product()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Product');
    }
}
```

So, say I want to get all products along with the highest priced bidding I did something like this.

```
$productBidding = DB::table('biddings')
                 ->select('*', DB::raw('max(price) as price'))
                 ->join('products', 'products.id', '=', 'biddings.product_id')
                 ->groupBy('product_id')
                 ->get();
```

That works well BUT I kinda want to do it Eloquent way. So how do I convert Query Builder way to Eloquent? I am currently on this but do not know how to put the "max" condition in.

```
$productBidding = Products::with('biddings')
            ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$productbinding=Bidding:with('product')
              ->get();

foreach($productbinding as $productbind) 
{
   echo $productbind->product->name;  // example
}
```

Comment: That's not what I meant, when I am using ::with to "join" Bidding and Product I want to get the bidding that has the highest price only.

Comment: Product and Bidding models between relationship create. Using call the model as above. You must use model relationship. Relationship, see your job.

Answer (score 0):

I would extract the highest bid to a separate function on the Product model, like so:

```
public function highestBid() {
    return $this->biddings()->max('price');
}
```

Then fetch the products and get the highest bid:

```
$products = Product::get();

foreach ($products AS $product) {
    echo $product->highestBid();
}
```

Comment: I am looking for a single Eloquent query to get the same result set as my Fluent query. What I want to achieve is similar to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291506/sql-query-to-select-distinct-row-with-minimum-value but on Eloquent.