# how to select one row from several rows with minimum value

Tags: sql, sql-server

The question based on [SQL query to select distinct row with minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15291506/5510499).
Consider the table:

```
id  game   point
1    x      1
1    y      10
1    z      1
2    x      2
2    y      5
2    z      8
```

Using suggested answers from mentioned question (select the ids that have the minimum value in the point column, grouped by game) we obtain

```
id  game   point    
1    x      1
1    z      1
2    x      2
```

The question is how to obtain answer with single output for each ID. Both outputs

```
id  game   point    
1    x      1
2    x      2
```

and

```
id  game   point    
1    z      1
2    x      2
```

are acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by point asc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you! Wonderful. That's a discovery for me.

Comment: What if I have an additional field I want to partition by... For examle, `filial`. Is there more elegant solution except `partition by cast(id as varchar(MAX)) + cast(filial as varchar(MAX))`?

Comment: @VadimShkaberda . . . `partition by id, filial order by . . . `.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Strangely enough that `partition by id, filial order by` gave me an error first time I tried it. Now it's Ok.

Answer (score -1):

We assume that all point entries are distinct(for each id and it's game so we can obtain the minimum of each id with it's game), Using a subquery and an inner join with two conditions would give you the result you,re waiting for.If it doesnt work with you I got another solution :

```
SELECT yt.*,     
FROM Yourtable yt INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT ID, MIN(point) MinPoint
        FROM Yourtable
        GROUP BY ID
    ) t ON yt.ID = t.ID AND yt.Record_Date = yt.MinDate
```