# Fetching data from group by having min value in laravel

Tags: laravel

I want to fetch the data from database in laravel, which looks like this.

```
id | model_id | price
1 |1 | 200
2 |1 | 100
3 |2 | 500
4 |2 | 300
5 |2 | 400
```

I want the result as :

```
id | model_id | price
2 |1 | 200
4 |2 | 300
```

This is my code :

```
Model::modelfilter(Input::only('model_id', 'price'))->groupBy('model_id')->havingRaw('MIN(price)')->get();
```

Thank you.

Comment: just add a 'where' condition to your query

Comment: It should be dynamic.

Comment: where will you get the dynamic value from

Comment: Model::modelfilter(Input::only('model_id', 'price'))->groupBy('model_id')->havingRaw('MIN(price)')->get();

I will pass model_id & price.

Comment: so you want records where price is >= a certain value?

Comment: Price is not mandatory.

Answer (score 2):

Try this one,

```
$results = ModelName::select(['*',DB::raw('MIN(price) as min_price')])
              ->groupBy('model_id')
              ->get();
```

For Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions

Comment: I'm getting only min_price, I'm not getting other data.

Comment: I got data like this, 

    id | model_id | price
    1 |1 | 200
    3 |2 | 300

price is replacing for wrong data.

I want like this, what can be done ?

    id | model_id | price
    1 |1 | 200
    4 |2 | 300

Comment: Did you replace `->groupBy('id')` with `->groupBy('model_id')`. I got it wrong there!

Comment: You need to join the same table again to get those results. Refer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/15292049/4584028    and  https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/join-same-table-with-two-columns. I think you cannot do it with the eloqount, you need to use the `DB::raw`