# How to fetch row having minimum value from sub-query in ORACLE database?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I have a table `Saledetail` with columns `prodid` ID of the Product and `Quantity` quantity sold for that Product . Now I am trying to fetch the ProductId with minimum sale made.

After going through some resource like: [SQL query to select distinct row with minimum value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291506/sql-query-to-select-distinct-row-with-minimum-value)

I wrote this query

```
select prodid, sum(quantity) as total_sum_for_prod
from saledetail
group by prodid
```

and its output is:

```
+--------+-----------------------+
| PRODID | total_sum_for_prod    |
+--------+-----------------------+
|    102 | 11                    |
|    101 |  5                    |
|    104 |  4                    |
|    106 |  4                    |
|    103 |  2                    |
+--------+-----------------------+
```

Now in order to get `prodid` with the minimum value of `total_sum_for_prod` column, I will have to use `select min(total_sum_for_prod) from above output`. And when I am trying to get that row from the subquery, I am getting an error.

I would like to know how to get my requirement done?

In case any better solution that is also welcome.

Thank you

Comment: *in order to get prodid having minimum value of k, i will have to use `select min(k) from table_name`* Simply sort by `sum` and take 1st record.

Comment: What is k in your out output and that is never the out put of your first query. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Nope, it's not working in my compiler. It's showing 'ORA-00936: missing expression.

Comment: @abhishek: If you get ORA-00936, then your DBMS is Oracle, not MySQL. These are two different database management systems. Which is your Oracle version? (Run `SELECT * FROM v$version;`).

Comment: Version 12.1.0.2.0. Thank you. since, i am a beginner in dbms , that's why i couldn't differentiate mysql and oracle.

Comment: Okay, I've updated my answer to show the Oracle solution. (Which is also the solution in standard SQL, i.e. valid for all DBMS that comply with the standard in this regard.)

Comment: since, the sub-query is also a table. Is there any way to alias that with a name, so that it can be used like a table, As i tried to do? Can it be done in my case? Thank you.

Comment: So far you have only shown a query without a subquery. But yes, a subquery is also a table and you can give it a name. In the following example I select all user last names in a subquery and call this subquery last_names: `select * from (select distinct last_name from users) last_names;`.

Comment: You can also use a with clause. In your example: `with sums as (select prodid, sum(quantity) as k from saledetail group by prodid) select * from sums where k = (select min(k) from sums);`, which is probably what you have been looking for. I have added this to my answer.

Comment: @nbk thank you for your concern, i got the same output as stated in my question, basically i aliased the attribute name. And i'm also a beginner so i didn't know about so much critical things, that had to be considered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Oracle

To get the product(s) with the minimum total in Oracle, use `FETCH FIRST ROWS`:

```
select prodid, sum(quantity) as sum_quantity
from saledetail
group by prodid
order by sum(quantity)
fetch first rows with ties;
```

An alternative using your original query is:

```
with sums as 
(
  select prodid, sum(quantity) as sum_quantity 
  from saledetail 
  group by prodid
)
select * 
from sums
where sum_quantity = (select min(sum_quantity) from sums);
```

### MySQL

This query gives you one product with the minimum quantity sum:

```
select prodid, sum(quantity) as sum_quantity
from saledetail
group by prodid
order by sum(quantity)
limit 1;
```

There is no ties clause for `LIMIT`, however. So, if two products or more share the same minimum total, above query would pick one of them arbitrarily.

Here is a simple query to get *all* products with the minimum quantity sum:

```
select prodid, sum(quantity) as sum_quantity
from saledetail
group by prodid
having sum(quantity) =
(
  select sum(quantity)
  from saledetail
  group by prodid
  order by sum(quantity)
  limit 1
);
```

As of MySQL 8 you can use a window  function in order to read the table only once:

```
select prodid, sum_quantity
from
(
  select 
    prodid,
    sum(quantity) as sum_quantity,
    min(sum(quantity)) over () as min_sum_quantity
  from saledetail
  group by prodid
) aggregated
where sum_quantity = min_sum_quantity;
```

<sub>Both Oracle queries and the last MySQL query are standard SQL. MySQL doesn't support `fetch first rows with ties`, so the first Oracle query does not work in MySQL. The second using a `WITH` clause works as of MySQL 8.</sub>