# SQL Select by MIN

Tags: sql-server

In my SQL Server 2014, I have this SQL query :

```
SELECT
    MIN (dbo.GetActualValue(Price_Value, Discount)) AS ActualPrice, 
    IDHOTEL
FROM
    HotelRoom
GROUP BY
    IDHOTEL
```

```
dbo.GetActualValue  => return @Price_Value - ((@Discount * @Price_Value) / 100)
```

How I can select `Price_Value`, `Discount` at the `MIN` value ?

I need to calculate the price after discount (actual price), find out the minimum price after calculation (min actual price) I need to select the original price, discount at the place with the smallest actual price

Comment: You should inline `dbo.GetActualValue` otherwise your query won't be parallelizable (using `INLINE = ON` if you're on SQL Server 2019).

Comment: thank for reply me, but I am using sql 2014

Comment: Actually, regardless, scalar functions are pretty sucky in SQL Server and should generally be avoided. Like Dai mentioned, your query (or any consumers of it) won't be able to be parallelized. You should just write the logic directly in your query. Use Views or Procedures to refactor and re-use code.

Comment: Also it's not super clear what you're stuck on? Your query should do what you said you want it to do.

Comment: i need to calculate the price after discount(actual price), find out the minimum price after calculation(min actual price)
I need to select the original price, discount at the place with the smallest actual price

Comment: @Phamvanphuong https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15291506/sql-query-to-select-distinct-row-with-minimum-value

Comment: @Phamvanphuong  `How I can select Price_Value, Discount at the MIN value?` min value of what? ActualPrice? or Price_Value?

Answer (score 0):

what you need is `Subquery` and `Max` or `Min` function

```
SELECT H.IDHOTEL,H.Price_Value,H.Discount,B.ActualPrice
FROM 
(SELECT dbo.GetActualValue(Price_Value, Discount) AS ActualPrice,Discount,Price_Value    
IDHOTEL FROM HotelRoom) H
JOIN 
(SELECT Min(dbo.GetActualValue(Price_Value, Discount)) AS ActualPrice,    
IDHOTEL FROM HotelRoom
GROUP  BY IDHOTEL) B
H.IDHOTEL=B.IDHOTEL AND B.ActualPrice=H.ActualPrice
```

Comment: I need select Price_Value and  Discount also bro

Comment: yes, bro, I need find Min(ActualPrice) and Discount,Price_Value  that related

Comment: I need query only min ActualPrice for each IDHOTEL , bro, your query dont map with my requirement

Comment: but this dont have Price_Value, Discount.  I need Price_Value,Discount ActualPrice when ActualPrice for each IDHOTEL (group by IDHOTEL)