# Fetch min() from other table with multiple relations

Tags: php, mysql, inner-join, min

I'm trying to create a full-text-search for products.desc. As response I want

- Products: id, desc
- Prices: The lowest priced-row in relation to
  products.id
- Suppliers: id, name of the supplier offering that price.

I'm currently using

```
SELECT products.id, MIN(prices.price) as prices_price, prices.id as prices_id, products.desc, products.product_number, prices.supplier_id, suppliers.name FROM products
 INNER JOIN prices
 ON prices.product_id = products.id
 INNER JOIN suppliers
 ON prices.supplier_id = suppliers.id
 WHERE 
 MATCH (products.desc) AGAINST ('test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
 GROUP BY prices.product_id
```

This is returning the correct (lowest) price, although the value for all the other prices.*-rows is undetermined/wrong. Since GROUP BY prices.product_id fetches the columns/rows with the lowest ID.

```
    Products
    id | desc
    ----------------------------------------
    1  | product_1
    2  | product_2


    Prices
    id | product_id | price | supplier_id
    ------------------------------------------------
    1  | 1          | 100   | 1
    2  | 1          | 150   | 2
    3  | 2          | 200   | 2
    4  | 2          | 250   | 1

    Suppliers
    id | name
    ------------------------------------------------
    1  | Supplier1  
    2  | Supplier2
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to get the lowest price by joining on a subquery grouping the prices and returning lowest price and corresponding product_id.

Then join again on the prices table to get the dataset of the lowest price.

Then use the supplier_id of the lowest price dataset to join the supplier.

[Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/93bba6/1)

```
SELECT
    products.id,
    lowestPrice.price,
    prices.id AS prices_id,
    products.desc,
    prices.supplier_id,
    suppliers.name
FROM
    products
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
        prices.price,
        prices.product_id
    FROM
        prices
    GROUP BY
        product_id
    HAVING
        MIN(prices.price)
) AS lowestPrice ON lowestPrice.product_id = products.id
INNER JOIN prices ON prices.price = lowestPrice.price AND prices.product_id = lowestPrice.product_id
INNER JOIN suppliers ON prices.supplier_id = suppliers.id
WHERE 
 MATCH (products.desc) AGAINST ('test*' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Comment: Thx, Although it returns: `#1111 - Invalid use of group function`?

Comment: ah sorry, fixing it

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't work. This Query fetches all the rows matching the search-query. Also it doesn't group. I read this questing although didn't help much..: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561774/mysql-fetching-lowest-value

Comment: I added a fiddle to the answer, can you adjust it so it fits your setup to reproduce the error?