# MySQL Order By X then Group By Y then Arrange Z Alphabatically

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I would like to 1) Order by Price ASC (show cheapest) then 2) Group By Item name then 3) Sort Alphabatically by Item name.

Here are 2 colums (will only include the 2 relevant columns, there are other colums like model, color etc..) 
[image]

Results I want:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Fetching lowest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561774/mysql-fetching-lowest-value)

Comment: What are the other columns and how do you want them shown in the output?  The answer will require grouping which means all columns are relevant.

Comment: It's not clear what you want.

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: What have you tried????  Learn how to ask question.  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Item, Min(Price), Other_Columns FROM table GROUP BY Item ORDER BY Item
```

IF you want the Id, color, and model that belong to the min price, things get complicated. You could use something like:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE id IN 
    (SELECT MIN(id) FROM `table` T1 WHERE Price=
        (SELECT MIN(Price) FROM `table` T2 WHERE T1.Item=T2.Item) 
     GROUP BY Item, Price)
```

Basically what you do is:first establish the min price per Item. Than find all the first id's from every Item with that price. Than select all the columns from all the records with those Id's. Probably it can be done simpler, but this is easiest to understand.

Iam not sure f that is what you want, since your question was not very specific/clear (hence all the negative votes). But I sort of came to believe it is.

Comment: Not wrong results, right but unpredictable results. Since he hasn't specified what he wants from the other columns, it's the best we can offer.

Comment: `SORT BY` in mysql? its `ORDER BY`

Comment: "Not wrong results, right but unpredictable results" yea i meant unrelated data.. Besides this query will not even run if the server has enabled only_full_group_by as a sql mode

Comment: Raymond. "Other_Columns" is OBVIOUSLY a placeholder for whatever the OP wants to do, which he didn't state. So filling that in is up to him, not to me. let him replace it by whatever MIN or MAX or GROUP_CONCAT or whatever he needs. I or nobody else can make any more of it.

Comment: @Roemer, you are on the right path, as stated in my question, OTHER CLOUMNS are (color, model and obviously id), now how can they correspond with the coulmn Item and Price which is working exactly how I want it from your query but color and model are mixed up?

Comment: You first have to specify WHICH id, model en color you want. If you want the id, color, model  that comes with tghe minimum price, things get complated. I'll update the answer for that.

Comment: I added another answer. Note that you still haven't made clear what you exactly want. Obviously, you want info about the cheapest version of each item. But do you want the info of ONE of each of the cheapest items (there may be several cars that cost exactly the minimum), or ALL of them? If the answer is ALL, replace `MIN(id)` by `id`.