# mysql show cheapest product price from store

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have table cheques, where I insert cheques.
Some are from same store and products and prices repeats.

So I want query product which store is cheapest price.

My Mysql table:

```
    +----------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+
    |    ID    |    Product_Name     |   price   |  discount_price |  store_id |
    +----------+---------------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+
    |    1     |   Banana 200g       |    1.25   |       0         |     1     | 
    |    2     |    Red bull 0.5l    |    2.20   |      1.90       |     1     | 
    |    3     |    Red bull 0.5l    |    2.20   |      1.90       |     1     | 
    |    4     |    Banana 300g      |    1.50   |       0         |     2     |
    |    5     |    Red bull 0.5l    |    2      |       0         |     2     |
    +----------+---------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+
```

Second question how I can calculate or query price of 1kg? or if 1kg banana price is 5$ and you buy 0.200g then it calculates it with query or should do it with php?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL - Fetching lowest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561774/mysql-fetching-lowest-value)

Comment: that's gonna be complicated because the values aren't seperated...Can't you change the way the data is put into database? (seperate "banana" from "200g")

Comment: @Jeff how I must separate tables then? I put products to database by cheques, I have grocery store cheque and i submit all products and prices to database.. But i must create different tables?

Comment: Where is the PHP code? Is it relevant at all?

Comment: I didnt know how to do, to query all data or possible to do this all with php. @Dharman

Comment: The question is about SQL problem, there is no PHP code or mention of it in the question. Remove PHP tag and add SQL tag.

Comment: I'd have a Product table (with basicly just the name and an id, maybe a brand,..), a store table, and a table that lists the products of stores (two id columns) with their prices (and a column for unit, anotherone for amountOfUnit).

Comment: @jeff but yeah qty but if I have product with grams based on kg price? is it possible to calculate? Can you do example of tables structures?

Comment: it only a matter of how you sanitize/serialize the data before you put it in the database. You could either always store gramms, or calculate based on what you have in unit-column. You could even (a bit9 overdo it and have a seperate table for units with a factor stored that gets you your default unit (like: g - 1, mg - 1000, kg - 0,01, l - 1, ml - 1000, dl - 10, m - 1, km - 0,01,..)

Comment: This is something of a frequently asked question

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't answer the question, I know.
It only shows an example of a table structure that would make your question (and therefor your problem) much easier to solve. Because you asked for it.

```
Products
+----+--------+-----------+
| id |  name  |   brand   |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 1  | banana | chicita   |
+----+--------+-----------+
| 2  | banana | fairtrade |
+----+--------+-----------+

Prices
+---------+-------+----------+------+-------+
| product | store | quantity | unit | price |
+---------+-------+----------+------+-------+
| 1       | 2     | 200      | g    | 0,60  |
+---------+-------+----------+------+-------+
| 1       | 56    | 1        | kg   | 1,20  |
+---------+-------+----------+------+-------+
| 2       | 56    | 0,5      | kg   | 1,00  |
+---------+-------+----------+------+-------+

Units (should have an id, too. Made for readability here)
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+
| unit |    factor   | unitgroup| locale | isDefault |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+
| g    | 1           | weight   | europe | true      |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+
| kg   | 0,01        | weight   | europe | false     |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+
| ml   | 0,001       | volume   | europe | false     |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+
| dl   | 0,1         | volume   | europe | false     |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+
| l    | 1           | volume   | europe | true      |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+
| m    | 1           | distance | europe | true      |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+
| km   | 0,001       | distance | europe | false     |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+
| mile | 0,000621371 | distance | us     | false     |
+------+-------------+----------+--------+-----------+
```

With a structure kind of like that you can find the lowest price in one sql query with some Left Joins, a MIN() and some calculations inside that.

Comment: Note that group is a reserved word, and hence a poor choice for a table/column identifier

Comment: @Strawberry true, I'll change that!

Comment: @Jeff why use column "isDefualt" what I can do or what i must do with that column?

Comment: with a column "isDefault" your app would know what unit it should display as standard and you would know for what unit you'd have to calculate the price for. Just a suggestion. You could also have a "unit" column in products table, so that bananas are showed/displayed in g, mellons in kg. All this would only be presets for output.