# Show only rows sorted by Field 1 where Field 2 includes the first distinct value

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create a statement which results in a table sorted by Field 1, showing only the rows where a distinct value of Field 2 appears for the first time.

Since my case is a bit hard to describe, here a visualization of what I am looking for.

My table:

| ID | Field 1 | Field 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | ttt |
| 2 | AA | ttt |
| 3 | AA | uuu |
| 4 | AA | vvv |
| 5 | AA | vvv |
| 6 | BB | xxx |
| 7 | BB | xxx |

Desired output:

| ID | Field 1 | Field 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | AA | ttt |
| 3 | AA | uuu |
| 4 | AA | vvv |
| 6 | BB | xxx |

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Fetching lowest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561774/mysql-fetching-lowest-value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your MySQL version support `ROW_NUMBER` window function you can try this.

```
SELECT id,Field1,Field2
FROM (
    SELECT *,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Field1,Field2 ORDER BY ID) rn
    FROM T
) t1
WHERE rn = 1
```

or try to use self-join with subquery

```
SELECT t2.*
FROM (
    SELECT MIN(ID) Id
    FROM T
    GROUP BY Field1,Field2
) t1 INNER JOIN t2
ON t1.Id = t2.Id
```

Comment: row_number is supported and this variant does the job perfectly, thanks a lot for your super quick reply.

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to filter based in the aggregate of `Field2`

sorting just by `field1` however is ambugious, for your desired results you need to sort by both columns, or the `id` column.

```
select * 
from t
where t.id in (select Min(id) from t group by field2)
order by field1, field2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! I applied your statement to my real data and noticed that - in comparison to the row_number() version from @D-Shih - a few entries were missing. After adjusting the 'group by' to field1 and field2 both statements have the same output 

Comment: Ok, yes that essentially is the same. It's not needed for your sample data as presented, but clearly that doesn't represent your real-life scenario.

Comment: Absolutely. For the sample data shown above your solution is on point.