# MySQL sorts data by one type first, and then groups the first data by the other types

Tags: mysql, sorting

MySQL sorts data by one type first, and then groups the first data by the other types

date

| name | age | sex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 20 | 1 |
| b | 25 | 2 |
| c | 30 | 2 |
| d | 18 | 1 |

result

| name | age | sex |
| --- | --- | --- |
| b | 25 | 2 |
| d | 18 | 1 |

```
select * from (select * from users order by sex desc ,age ) temp group by temp.sex order by sex desc
```

Comment: Please ask a question.

Comment: 1) Your ORDER BY used in the subquery is ignored in outer query. 2) Your query is illogical because of the GROUP BY is incomplete, so all columns values except one used in GROUP BY expression (sex) returns indefinite value from all ones in a group.

Comment: How to query the minimum age group information data based on gender

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL - Fetching lowest value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12561774/mysql-fetching-lowest-value)